# How do I programmatically assign a new book when a new node is created?

Tags: hooks, 9, nodes

For a given content type, if a new node is created and no book is assigned, I'd like to create a new book and assign the new node to that book.

(some background - that content type is the book cover, and for editors to create a new book I ask them to create a cover first. this makes more sense for them. The 'add child page' links will then appear automatically. I know they can select 'new book' on the create page, but that makes no sense in that context - alternatively, if I could have that selected by default, that would work )

Comment: note to self: `create a new book` is misleading here, because a book is not an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @rafael 's answer:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 *
 * - assigns a new book for a new MYCONTENTTYPE if none was selected
 */

function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'MYCONTENTTYPE' 
    && property_exists($node,'book') 
    && empty($node->book['bid'])) {
      $node->book['bid'] = 'new';
      $node->book['plid'] = 0;
      $node->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a hook implementation in a custom module

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  // Check if the node is of the desired content type and no book is assigned.
  if ($node->getType() == 'my_content_type' && empty($node->book['bid'])) {
  // Get the book storage handler.
  $bookStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('book');

  // Create a new book entity.
  $book = $bookStorage->create(array(
    'type' => 'book',
    'title' => $node->getTitle(),
    'uid' => $node->getOwnerId(),
  ));
    $book->save();

    // Assign the node to the new book.
    $node->book['bid'] = $book->id();
    $node->book['plid'] = 0;
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Allthough - apparently, I do not want to 'create new book' because book is not an entity. I just want to 'assign a new book'. I got a working version from your code, but adding it as a separate answer.

Comment: Yes, a book is not a content entity, which means there is not any storage handler for books and `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('book')` will not return any class instance.